# How to deal with colleagues who smoke and carry a bad breath to meeting rooms?

Tags: professionalism, colleagues

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I approach a co-worker on matters of personal hygiene?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/621/how-should-i-approach-a-co-worker-on-matters-of-personal-hygiene)

I spend 3 hours of my time on an average everyday in meeting rooms.  The rooms are generally very small and people sit close to each other.  I have few colleagues (from another team) who smoke cigarettes.  Some are contractors from another vendor and some are regular employees.  They come to the meeting room right after smoking.  Some of them don't use gums.  Some don't wash their mouth either.  It smells very bad.  It is not only me but my other non-smoking colleagues share the same uncomfortable feeling.

Is it appropriate for me to tell them on their face that they should use gums or wash their mouth before entering the meeting room (I don't want them to think I am rude.  I just want to ask politely but the conversation might end up messy)?

Or Should I just escalate and leave the matters to my boss?

Both the above has some probability that they don't heed to my request.  As I mentioned, there are some people who are not regular employees.  What can be done in that case?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What would you do with someone who wore too much aftershave? What if they had body odour? Bad breath? Do the same thing.

Comment: I think this is pretty different from personal hygiene as smokers often see this kind of attitude as an affront to their personal freedom (also they are addicted to smoking, so not as easy to remedy).

Comment: @pdr: I have encountered people who sometimes put too much cologne.  That was a different situation because I know that they did that to look good but unfortunately applied too much.  It was easy to tell them that the cologne smells really good but is a bit stronger.  And they gladly reduced the amount from the very next day.  Win-Win.  Body Odour, Bad Breath - I don't know.  I was looking at the question pointed out by Yannis Rizos.  I am not sure if those solutions can be applied to this case.

Comment: @tjb1982: No. Stopping someone from smoking at all leads to all those arguments, and only while the generation who used to be able to smoke everywhere grow old and die off (speaking as the youngest of that breed). Telling them that they smell and they're making you uncomfortable in meetings is exactly like telling a person with body odour or bad breath the same thing. For what it's worth, I would happily chew some gum before a meeting with Ramnath, if it made his life better.

Comment: @pdr +1 those are good points

Comment: Is there anyway the "solutions" proposed by the OP won't result in bad blood between him and the smokers?

Comment: I would object to spending 3 hours a day in meeting rooms.

Comment: @kolossus: "I hate to come off as one of *those* non-smokers, but we spend a lot of time in close-quarters in that meeting room and I'm finding the smell of smoke overpowering and uncomfortable. I don't want to tell you to stop smoking but is there anything we can do ... etc. etc."

Comment: You could request the boss to put a small poster in important areas to inform people about no smoking and breath. Its going to be neutral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As a former smoker, I can tell you that it would be very embarrassing to me if you confront me and so I would probably stop if you just tell me exactly what you wrote here. Especially if you tell me it makes you feel kind of gross. In the old days, I might have reacted by shittalking you when I go out to smoke (out of insecurity, some smokers have a penchant for sort of cliquish behavior), but in the end I think if you start conveying the message, your nonsmoking colleagues will support you and that would make me feel pretty uncomfortable and self conscious about it from then on.

But, yes, it is entirely appropriate to ask someone not to bring in an offensive and socially unacceptable odor, especially into a confined space.

Comment: The more I read this answer, the more I dislike it. Sorry. You are making a prejudgement about about a person's reaction, grouping all smokers' personalities together, and then you suggest using peer-pressure to make them do something about it.

Comment: Peer pressure is just a fact of life. I'm advocating being direct, but assuring the OP that peer pressure will take care of it from there. I'm not suggesting to *use* peer pressure as much as let it run its natural course.

Comment: Edited to make it more personal to my experience and not to be prejudiced

Comment: since when has cigarette smoke become a socially unacceptable odor?

Comment: Well, I can only speak to my own experience, and where I've lived, which has been for the past decade between North Carolina and Virginia, USA, that has certainly been my experience.

Comment: "since when has cigarette smoke become a socially unacceptable odor?"  Depends how you define it, but the trend is undeniably in that direction, starting in the 1970s and stronger than ever now.

Comment: As a current smoker I strongly disagree with this for two reasons. One, you don't have a right to never be offended. Two, being offensive about it doesn't improve the situation at all. You have every right to be privately offended by it, just like I'm offended by a myriad of stuff my co-workers do which I never mention. My advice, keep your mouth shut on this issue - you WILL look like the bad guy if you do anything.

Comment: Regardless of whether it **is** acceptable it **should be** socially acceptable to point out offensive odours and the likes as long as it's done in an inoffensive manner. Regardless, I would advise taking this up with the colleagues in question in a confidential fashion. Take them apart for a moment and explain to them that their fresh smoker's smell is making people uncomfortable in meetings and see what they do with that information. No sense in needlessly escalating a situation when there is a solution that will let everyone save face.