# How to approach co-workers who do not wash their hands?

Tags: work-environment, colleagues, ethics

We have all seen it, probably too many times: someone gets out of the toilet booth/cubicle and rushing outside, never even glancing towards the sink where he/she are expected to wash their hands like we all should be doing.

**First dilemma**: should I approach them while still in the bathroom? If so, how?

**Second dilemma**: suppose I know that person and later meet him/her and expected to shake hands. What can I do? Is there a gentle way to bring the issue up without sounding paternal?

*I am aware of this other question: [How should I approach a co-worker on matters of personal hygiene?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/621/how-should-i-approach-a-co-worker-on-matters-of-personal-hygiene), however it looks like the other question is focusing on bad smell and not discussing the habit of not washing hands, thus I don't think it fits as exact duplicate at its current state.*

Comment: @gnat the other question is about bad smell, not about washing hands in toilets, but if five high rep users here (or one mod) would decide it's an exact duplicate I won't fight the decision.

Comment: I see. I think there is a good chance for [de-duplicating edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773) on your question. Though given how [top answer over there](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/631/168) seems to fit your case, I somewhat doubt that it is worth the effort

Comment: Thanks @gnat think I'll try the edit approach when having some time.

Comment: Are you in the food service industry? Other people service? It's one thing if a construction worker goes back to shingling my roof and quite another if the person goes back to making my sandwich.

Comment: @Telastyn no and no. Office. I care only when I have to shake that person's hand, then I have to use my hand to eat sandwich. :)

Comment: I feel the same way at the gym as they are touching equipment used by others.  I have tried "dude wash your hands" a few times and the best I got was "go to ...".  We have one guy that will sit with his bare bottom on the chairs and I and others have asked him not to.

Comment: @Blam that's quite sad, but guess we can't do much about it. As for bare bottom isn't it considered public nudity which is forbidden in most places?

Comment: The locker room has a TV and some chairs.  They even put up a no bare bottom on the furniture sign and he does it right under the sign.  This guy is a whack job - he wants to be confronted so he can argue.

Comment: Shaking hands _ALWAYS_ risks transferring germs/viruses, from a sneeze or from something they handled. (See the various hyperbole comments on the web that kissing may actually be lower risk.)  The best and most effective way to protect yourself is to wash *your* hands more frequently and/or use alcohol sanitizer. Remember that most folks do "know better", and your reminding them isn't going to tell them anything they don't already know... so it's unlikely to change their habits, and they're more likely to be annoyed by the reminder than to appreciate it.

Comment: @Blam oh, didn't get you mean chairs in locker room. Guess in that case that guy gets what he wants without breaking any rules... :/

Comment: So you caught one person who doesn't wash their hands. How many people have you shaken hands with that you can absolutely guarantee washed their hands after the bathroom? After scratching their nose? Armpit? The only person you can count on to be clean is you, so if you have a problem with unwashed hands, then you'll have to refuse to shake anyone's hand because you can't know where that germ-magnet has been.

Comment: Same advice I got in grade school: Wash your own hands regularly and refrain from touching your face and mouth. It is not rocket science. You have no say or control over what people do or don't do in the toilet.

Comment: Closing this is a bad call.  This is a much more specific question than the one that it is proposedly a duplicate of and answers to it may be considerably more useful to some than the answers to the general hygiene question.

Comment: @BrentHackers not sure I agree, to be honest. The other question is "canonical", i.e. meant to serve as central point of information for all the related questions, where each aspect can have its own answer. It's common in Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange where I "come from", not sure about this site though. Anyway, answer specific only to the aspect of not washing hands after using toilets can be posted there instead of here, no harm will be done. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe. Honestly though, I'd say that the other question is too broad. "How should I approach a co-worker on matters of personal hygiene?" my first thoughts are "What sort of matters of personal hygiene? BO? Bad Breath? Is this an individual or a workplace culture?" These things would change my answer. To me, a hand-washing specific question would be more useful. In fact, I found this question very deliberately, because I wanted to know what others would do in the very situation described above. I don't feel like the other question is specific enough to generate those answers.

Comment: @BrentHackers please see [this discussion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263996/should-all-se-network-sites-only-accept-questions-that-have-a-single-acceptable) and [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265500/posting-an-intentionally-too-broad-unclear-catch-all-question). Bottom  line is that those are acceptable, to a limit, and looks like it's also valid here, otherwise the site regulars (I'm not one of them) and/or mods would have acted long ago. Anyway, luckily for both of us, I got couple of good answers here before it was closed. :)

Comment: @BrentHackers also, feel free to discuss more details with me in chat, I got link in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

That is not just a personal hygiene problem that is bad manners in general. 
If they are not considerate of others then they are most likely not going to accept input.

Often you have a break between ordering and being served.
Use that as a time to go to the restroom and wash your hands. 
It is a good idea to wash your hands before eating in general.
If it is a food court with no readily available restroom then it will typically be informal and less chance of shaking hands. 
If there is open food bar my policy is get some quick and just not eat after that person.
As a last resort "Just washed my hands and am getting ready to eat".
Or "Just went to the restroom and did not wash my hands and you are getting ready to eat."

Comment: +1 for *"Just went to the restroom and did not wash my hands and you are getting ready to eat."*, which is *exactly* the message you want to send.

Comment: Wanted to post my own answer.  I guess this is the one I agree with most.  Not washing is like letting kids attend a school without having their vaccinations.  If an individual (child/worker) is not doing their part to help prevent the spread of diseases and infections (getting immunised/washing hands), unless they have a good reason not to (immune deficiency/soap allergy?), then they are negating rather than contributing to a hygienic system. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Herd_immunity &  https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/10164/do-i-need-to-wash-my-hands-after-using-the-bathroom

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are not management and you have no authority over them, the only thing I can think of is to directly say "Thank you for washing your hands!" to the culprit as he is rushing past the sinks. I usually use an indirect approach, explicitly thanking the bloke next to me for washing his hands while the culprit is passing by the sinks. Of course, I am not above breathlessly telling the colleagues "Don't even think of shaking this guy's hand!" and spreading the rumor around the office that the culprit is not washing his hands.
2. If I have supervisory authority, a loud "Hey, wash your hands!" as the culprit is passing by the sinks should be sufficient.
3. Don't discount the power of example. Whether or not you are in authority, the culprit who sees you hunching over the sink and seeing you spending 30 seconds to wash your hands - that should make him self-conscious about rushing past the sinks without washing his hands. That's especially powerful if the culprit sees two or more of you thoroughly washing their hands.
4. Every restaurant in New York City is required to post an "Employees must wash their hands" sign. Maybe we should have management post such a sign in the workplace's bathrooms.

Why is there always someone on this site who is obsessed about how to approach somebody? Figure how how to say it and then say it. It's that simple.

Comment: It's all about how to do it without hurting the other person's feelings. Keep in mind he/she might be ranked higher than me, and not washing hands is not such a fatal felony: it's not like I seen him/her committing some horrible crime. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Have management put up the "Employees must wash their hands" sign. So far as I am concerned, anyone who does not wash his hands after doing their business HAS committed a horrible crime and should be dog shamed. I am thinking something like putting an "I did not wash my hands" placard around the culprit's neck and have the culprit stop at every cubicle to say hello to everyone - and I haven't even gotten started being creative yet :)

Comment: haha, good one. My idea for punishment would be to make him/her shake the hands of 10 other people right after visiting the toilet before washing their hands. But I fear it won't be legal! :-D

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's a totally minor issue, but I am blowing it out of proportion because I find it a personal irritant

Comment: If the question is not appropriate then why are you answering it?

Comment: @Blam Because that's what I choose to do. I have no particular psychological need to be a stickler for perfection.

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan: you appear to be thinking along [these lines](http://comedycontinent.blogspot.de/2011/01/didnt-wash-hands.html), are you?

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yeah, we should bend backwards to give them the recognition they deserve :)

Answer (score -3):

Just for your information, there is also an alternative reason to this, though as far as I am aware it may be more of a minority group:

I never wash my hands in the sink. Ever. Why? Because the sink handles and area itself may be dirty and full of germs. After washing I have to close the water anyway, and then I touch the handle/knob again.

What I do is I always keep antibacterial wipes or gel with me, which are also much more effective and faster than water in the toilet. And yes, I wipe myself back at my desk.

So it may just be that 20-30% of the people you see not washing their hands in the sink have wipes or gel at their desk.

Comment: You can always close the sink handles with a paper towel and use the same paper towel to open the restroom handle knob. I see people do this all the time.

Comment: @glowie, I thought about it, but the gel/wipes are just cooler :P

Comment: -1 so... you spread your yick hands on all the door handles on the way back to your desk? nice. also, hands sanitizers are not as effective as soap in a sink.

Comment: +1. In general, it's best to assume other people have good reasons for doing what they're doing.

Comment: just splash water on the sink handles and then kick the door open. 
Most public bathrooms have optical sensors anyway. While small workplace bathrooms usually have paper towels and stuff so you can use those to open doors. 

Also you can rinse your hands with water and then use the gel anyway. 

You should at least do this because it's not nice to other people to make the door knob dirty.

Comment: Our local health department says that wipes are ok when there is nothing else, no running water available, but that washing your hands under running water is the best way to remove germs.

Comment: -1 Feel free to wash your hands and then wipe them when you get back to your seat as well.  Anyone who doesn't want to touch surfaces that your unwashed hands have touched shouldn't have to.  The fact that 'other people don't have good hygiene anyway' is a really bad excuse for being as bad as them. I strongly disagree with (to the point of anger) anyone trying to justify this antisocial behaviour in this way.