# How should I approach my manager on matters of personal hygiene?

Tags: communication, work-environment, manager

I have joined my first job 6 months ago as a software developer at a big company. I am the youngest person in my team of 6. I like my team very much as all of the members are very cool and my manager is awesome. We meet twice every week (one hour meetings) for having a discussion on our project in a small room.

The problem is that there is a *very bad smell* coming whenever my manager opens his mouth. It has been difficult to bear the bad smell.

If he were a co-worker then I would follow: [How should I approach a co-worker on matters of personal hygiene?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/621/how-should-i-approach-a-co-worker-on-matters-of-personal-hygiene/) But he is my manager.
What is the best way to approach my manager about this?

Comment: I think the advice in that other question is still very valid.  If you are not comfortable talking to your boss (and who would be about such a thing?), then taking it to HR is an option.  They may send out a generic "personal hygeine" email to all staff, and hopefully he might get the hint.  If not, then HR should still be able to deal with it on your behalf.

Comment: Also remember that this may be a medical condition he is already doing everything he can about.

Comment: I don't think it's a dup and the advice in the other question worries me. In particular, the sentence "If they don't follow up on it, send them home." scares me. If the OP follows this, I am afraid there is a possibility that the person being sent home is the OP himself. Please see that [answer](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/631/1193)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my opinion, there is little difference (apart from the routes of escalation) whether you are approaching a peer or a manager - they both are people you need to work with.

Just speak to your manager in private, and mention what you remarked in a matter-of-fact manner. As usual, try hard to avoid sounding like you want to accuse him, just explain that it makes you uncomfortable.

It may well be that the smell is a medical problem the manager knows about but cannot change - in that case you could respectfully ask he be a bit mindful about keeping distance, but apart from that you'll probably have to live with it.

Also, you might consider asking a peer about this first (in private, and only if it's someone you trust). That may help you decide how (and if) you want to talk to your manager about it.

Comment: I would have a hard time telling my boss that his breath is unbearable.  Asking him to keep his distance because his breath stinks?  Unthinkable!  Surely there must be a better way.

Comment: @Lumberjack: I know it's not easy, but life isn't always easy :-). If you know a better way, put it into an answer. I could not think of a better way.